# ES6 cached loop error..?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create an ES6 class and I'm setting the length of the loop within the loop. Whenever I try to do it I get an error saying "len is undefined".

Example

```
class Test1
{
    constructor()
    {
        for (var i = 0; len = 10, i < len; i++) {
            console.log("hello");
        }
    }
}

var test = new Test1();
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined it in a wrong place.

```js
class Test1 {
  constructor() {
    for (var i = 0, len = 10; i < len; i++) {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  }
}

var test = new Test1();
```